# Android - Change container of Fragment

Tags: android, transactions, android-fragments, containers

i have a layout containing two framelayouts. The right frame layout contains a fragment, which  I want to move to the left frame layout.

Everything I tried results in *IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment*

Which transactions are the best to achieve it or do I have to create a new instance of the fragment in order to put it in the left container?

I hope someone can help me.

thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a way to resolve the problem above. Instead its only possible to create a new instance of the fragment and transfer the state from the old fragment to the new one.